# MVC one to zero inserting not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, insert-update

I am using EntityFramework. I have an "Application" object (which has a field certificateReasonID) which can have one or zero CertificateReasons - so there is a ralationship to the "CertificateReason" table, and visiually on the edmx diagram we do not see the certificateReasonTypeID field.

When I update an Application - it INSERTS a new CertificateReason and UPDATES Application.certificateReasonTypeID to the new ID - instead of updatig Application.certificateReasonTypeID to the selected ID.

The CertificateReason object is in an added state(technically correct).
The aspx code is

```
<%foreach (var certReason in Model.CertificateReasons)                  
                  { %>
                        <li>
                        <%= Html.RadioButton("CertificateReason.id", certReason.id)%>
                        <!-- only because it is adding when it shouldn't -we have to set the other non null values(i.e. not id) in the object else it will fail when it tries to save-->
                          <input type="hidden" value="<%= certReason.meaning %>" name="CertificateReason.meaning"/>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<%= certReason.effectiveFrom %>" name="CertificateReason.effectiveFrom"/>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<%= certReason.createdWhen %>" name="CertificateReason.createdWhen"/>
                        <label for="certificateReasonTypeID<%=certReason.meaning%>"><%=certReason.meaning%></label>
                        </li>
                <%}%>
```

The update code is

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection, ApplicationViewModel model)
 {
     var appToUpdate = OMF.Application.First(m => m.id == id);
     UpdateModel(movieToUpdate, collection.ToValueProvider()); 
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {

          OMF.ApplyPropertyChanges(movieToUpdate.EntityKey.EntitySetName, appToUpdate );
          OMF.SaveChanges();
      }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

answer was to pass the Application model into the Edit post - had to put a hidden field on form for the object to be filled correctly) and ensure I was getting the Application objetc not a var. Can't use the ModelState.IsValid as always false, but correctly updates not inserts. Other point was had to do an .Include("CertificateReasons") on the get.

public ActionResult Edit(Application app, FormCollection collection)
        {

```
        Application movieToEdit = OMF.GetApplication(app.id);           
        if(app.CertificateReason != null)
            movieToEdit.CertificateReason = OMF.CertificateReason.First(d => d.id == app.CertificateReason.id);
        TryUpdateModel(movieToEdit);

        //if (ModelState.IsValid) --can't use this
       // {
            OMF.SaveChanges();
       // }
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", app.id);

    }
```